# Python: Reflecting Image in black borders

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, image-processing

I'm currently trying to write a python script (python 3) that can create a reflection of an image on its black borders.

For starters, I'm using this image:

[image]

I would like its black borders (the two black triangles) replaced with the partial reflection of the image on the separating line between the triangles and the image. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you want it reflected horizontally or along the axis of the edge? One is much harder than the other.

Comment: Did you rotate the image yourself, or do you need to deal with images that already have this border?

Comment: @MarkRansom I want it reflected along the axis of the edge.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I rotated the image myself so I can use it as an example. I want to use it on images that have similar borders, maybe smaller ones but of similar shape

Comment: Too bad. I was hoping that you only wanted this for images that you rotate yourself. I would suggest you expand the image by mirroring before rotation (a trivial thing to implement).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve for the equation of each boundary line by sampling two pixels on or close to each line and solving for the slope and intercept.

Once you have those equations, then let `(x0, y0)` be one of the black pixels (say in the upper left) you want to reflect, and let's say that the equation for the left boundary is `y = m * x + b` (where you solved for `m` and `b` from two pixels along the boundary).

Then you can [get the reflection point `(xR, yR)`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851681/deriving-formula-for-reflection-over-y-mxb-using-dot-product):

```
# using Python syntax for example
d = (x0 + (y0 - b) * m) / (1 + m ** 2)
xR = 2 * d - x0
yR = 2 * d * m - y0 + 2 * b
```

and you can quantize `(xR, yR)` to the nearest pixel or something.

You can also try to automatically detect the edge lines with some type of edge detector along with a check that everything on one side of the edge is a zero pixel, and once you automate the task of getting the edge pixels, you could automatically determine the reflection line from any two coordinates along it.

Comment: Excellent answer! Finding that boundary line should be trivial considering there are very few pixels with an RGB value of exactly [0,0,0] in a natural image.